# Wget: convert-links and avoid redownloading already fetched files?

Tags: lubuntu, downloads, wget

I am downloading data spread among multiple files that don't change once published.

Therefore `--timestamping` is not good enough, because it is constantly checking whatever resource is changed, which is, in my case, completely pointless.

`--no-clobber` would fit perfectly. Unfortunately it doesn't work with `--convert-links`  for some reason.

> Both --no-clobber and --convert-links were specified, only
>   --convert-links will be used.

I hoped that `--backup-converted` would help but it changed nothing (it works for `--timestamping`.)

Why `wget --convert-links --backup-converted --no-clobber --wait 1 https://example.com` ignores `--no-clobber` and how could it be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

Here's why it doesn't work: it was disabled on purpose by the developers - http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?31781

As for how to fix it? Try installing a version of wget older than 1.12.1 - which seems to be the version when the aforementioned "bug" was fixed by the developers.